# php netbeans and mysql: how do i retrieve data from my database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, netbeans

i am very new to php and i am trying to work my way through it. i have a php project which was not written on my pc and i imported onto the netbeans, i also set up my mysql database and connected it with netbeans since i am running the project on netbeans, also, i am working with a code igniter framework. 
When i try to sign up, it doesn't sign me up, meaning my project doesn't see the database on my local server...anyone knows what i can do please? do i need to change some settings in my project? I tested my database connection on netbeans and it is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For code ignitior read this guide for connecting to the database:

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/connecting.html

Answer (score 0):

you can try this in your php script:

```
$db = mysqli_connect(host,username,password,dbname);
```

In frameworks, database connection is usually done in config file. I dont know code igniter but in Yii framework it is done in /config/main.php and looks like this:

```
'db'=>array(
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=databasename',
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => 'username',
        'password' => 'password',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ),
```

Comment: OK, i forgot to add, i am working with code igniter framework(will edit my question now) so where do i add that code please?

Comment: if you are using a framework, database connection must be in your config file. I don't know code igniter but in Yii framework, database connection is done in /config/main.php. Take a look at my edited answer

Comment: awesome...i found it on config/database and i used my frameworks settings...thanks